# Unatended script execution in ubuntu terminal

Tags: shell-script, utilities

I have installed Ubuntu on a VMWare virtual machine.

When I got to installing a VMWare tools, I have stumbled upon a simple question:

If I execute a script (perl script in VMWare tools case), is there a way for me to tell the execution beforehand, that if it prompts me for an input, given that it has a default value, it just uses it, not waiting for me to press Enter?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean, and what your end goal is? By 'default' do you mean enter the same string for every input, or separately for each?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`yes` is designed for this purpose; it outputs the same string to stdout continuously, so you can pipe it into another script and it will keep answering the same for every prompt. It defaults to `y` so it can say "yes" to the prompts, but if you just want it to send a newline each time you can pass it the empty string as an argument:

```
$ yes '' | vmware-script
```

Comment: Thank you. So even if I want to be sending newline of each prompt, I still use $ yes '' as shown in your example?

Comment: @Maxim It outputs whatever string you give it, followed by a newline, so if you give it an empty string it will output just the newline. I used two single-quotes; `yes ""` will also work

Answer (score 4):

Either patch the source to have a default, or use a here document or here string to send your input to the script's `stdin`:

```
./script << EOF
answer 1
answer 2
...
answer N
EOF
```

Certain programs may not accept this (usually ones handling authentication which may disable this for security purposes). In this case, look into using something like [`expect`](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm).